# SquidGee Dry System to prevent water seepage in basement?

Tags: water, basement, waterproofing, water-pressure, sealing

One of the rooms in my basement has water seepage shown in the following:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Some work has been done to patch the honey combs. Due to limited budget, I can only do interior waterproofing. I plan on removing the lower section of the wood frame and apply the SquidDee Dry System like this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5KnxcGePpM&list=PLNNHq4pxt9Gxe5UFLf5s1PjGhaqAGUu7h&index=4&t=15s). Is there a good chance of success to solve the water seepage problem with such approach and with my current basement water seepage issue?

Comment: Get the outdoor surface water draining away from the house.  Unless you have a water table higher than that (doubtful) then 90% plus of your seepage can be solved by changing the surface drainage pattern.

Comment: There is a downspout directing rain water away from the house, are there other methods I should explore?

Comment: Hi Tyson, can you explain what are the methods to lead the outdoor surface water draining away from the house?

Comment: In general you need to have a positive slope away from the house. (Not “flat” or “close-to-slopping” but actually 6” inches higher at the foundation than 3 feet away) Without seeing and walking around (and even watching it rain) at your house it’s hard to say what specifically you need to do.  Usually tho overtime the dirt around a foundation settles over time, drainage toward the foundation is a problem, and it results in exactly this type of thing.  Make sure there is a positive slope away from the foundation for the less than obvious running water.